# How to keep a crosshair out from the margins in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to understand the logic behind this chart : http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/6eb506b129f585ce5c8a  made by D3noob.
I have tried to add a focus line from the focus circle to right before the margin.
I found a partial solution which is :

```
// append the x line_up 
    focus.append("line")
        .attr("class", "x_track_line_up")
        .style("stroke", "black")
        .style("stroke", "3,3")
        .style("opacity", 0.9)
        .attr("y1", 0)
        .attr("y2", height);

//call the x line   
    focus.select(".x_track_line_up")
      .attr("transform",
            "translate(" + x(d.date) + "," +
                           y(d.close) + ")")
            .attr("y2", -height - y(d.close));
```

The only problem is that this added line is also drawn in the top margin.
I believe that the issue here is the last line of this portion of code but I am not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `translate`. Just do:

```
focus.select(".x_track_line_up")
    .attr("x1", x(d.date))
    .attr("x2", x(d.date))
    .attr("y2", y(d.close));
```

Here is the updated bl.ocks: http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/dd1bb9adda42e4bc9768e9a35432197a

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.